# How do I get Laravel to specify my charset in all responses?

Tags: php, laravel, character-encoding, laravel-5

Yes, I know I should be using UTF-8, but I need to use windows-1252 charset encoding.

I know I can do it by hardcoding the base Synfony response class 
Response.php,

`$charset = $this->charset ?: 'windows-1252';`

but that's ugly as hell.

I can't find where to set it from the config files. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change charset in the middleware:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetCharset
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=windows-1252');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Just make sure that all the content you return is in proper encoding.

Comment: It doesn't work... Maybe the middleware is changing the charset AFTER the headers have been set?

Comment: Have you enabled the middleware in Kernel.php? Could you make sure it is run by doing dd('test') in its handle method?

Comment: Yes, I did, actually I can see the charset successfully changed: #charset: "windows-1252"

Comment: Question is the variable "charset" is successfully changed. But the class Response uses this variable to set the header "Content-Type", but the header is still "text/html; charset=UTF-8". If I hard code the variable in the Response class, then it successfully sets the header to "text/html; charset=windows-1252". It looks like middleware sets the charset too late, maybe?

Comment: This will override all response content-types forcing 'text/html'. What if you want to output a json response, wich needs 'application/json'?

Comment: Just check the content type header set in the $response and don't update it if json is specified

Answer (score 1):

Improvement to [answer by @jedrzej.kurylo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31585105/3549014) to change charset only if content type is `text/html`.

```php
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetCharset
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $contentType = $response->headers->get('Content-Type');
        if (strpos($contentType, 'text/html') !== false) {
            $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=windows-1252');
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Put SetCharset.php in `app/Http/Middleware` folder, and then modify `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add the class reference at the end of `$middleware` array property:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    // ... Other middleware references
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetCharset::class,
];
```